# How to add indexed arrays to an array on a certain index using PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to add indexed arrays to a final array on a certain index. So far, I have tried this:

```
$lista = array();
$id = '1234';

$lista2 = array(
    'chave1' => 'valor1',
    'chave2' => 'valor2',
    'chave3' => 'valor3'
);

$lista3 = array(
    'chave4' => 'valor4',
    'chave5' => 'valor5',
    'chave6' => 'valor6'
);

array_push($lista[$id], $lista2);
array_push($lista[$id], $lista3);
```

But it's not working. The final array on the $id index has NULL value. What am I missing? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_push` is used for appending something to the end of array, it should not be used with specific key. You want something more like this:

```
<?php
$lista = array();
$id = '1234';

$lista2 = array(
    'chave1' => 'valor1',
    'chave2' => 'valor2',
    'chave3' => 'valor3'
);

$lista3 = array(
    'chave4' => 'valor4',
    'chave5' => 'valor5',
    'chave6' => 'valor6'
);

$lista[$id] = $lista2 + $lista3;

print_r($lista);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [1234] => Array
        (
            [chave1] => valor1
            [chave2] => valor2
            [chave3] => valor3
            [chave4] => valor4
            [chave5] => valor5
            [chave6] => valor6
        )

)
```

EDIT:

If you need it in loop (which does not look correct, so you should reconsider structure of your code...):

```
<?php
$lista = array();
$id = '1234';

$lista1 = array(
    'chave7' => 'valor7',
    'chave8' => 'valor8',
    'chave9' => 'valor9'
);

$lista2 = array(
    'chave1' => 'valor1',
    'chave2' => 'valor2',
    'chave3' => 'valor3'
);

$lista3 = array(
    'chave4' => 'valor4',
    'chave5' => 'valor5',
    'chave6' => 'valor6'
);
$lista[$id] = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $lista[$id] += ${'lista' . $i};
}
print_r($lista);
```

Comment: Oh I see.. But what if I'm inside a loop? Instead of 2 arrays, I need to add 35 arrays like that?

Comment: Loop of arrays sounds like a bad design and you potentially need to reconsider your code. However, there is a way to do this: `$lista[$id] += ${'lista' . $i};` where $i is iterative variable in your `for` loop, if your arrays are indexed... But as I said this is a bad pattern

Comment: I tested your coude here, It's funny cause it's adding only $lista1 and $lista3 to the main array.

Comment: @churros It is adding all of those, just that I wrote same key names for array 1 and 2. My bad. See update

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the value directly: `$lista[$id] = $lista2;`

Comment: I need to add more than one array.